# How is data sorted in the Cassandra memtable in the absence of a clustering key?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and was checking in how cassandra internals work. I checked [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html) article and in this its stated that memtable is stored in sorted order.

But if there's no clustering key or multilple culstering keys, how cassandra store the data in that case in memtable? I want to know what is the criteria of sorting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways where data is sorted when it comes to Cassandra.

The term "SSTable" stands for "sorted string table" meaning that the contents of a Cassandra data file are sorted. Data in memtables are sorted by the partition key so that they are already ordered when they are flushed to disk.

Additionally, it also makes it easy for Cassandra to determine whether a partition exists in an SSTable or not since it keeps metadata about the first and last partition key contained in the SSTable.

If the table has clustering columns, the rows are sorted based on the clustering order defined in the table schema. This is the only time where clustering keys are relevant for sorting. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!